# Is there a GUI tool for managing systemd on Ubuntu 18.04 (Bionic Beaver)?

Tags: gui, systemd, 18.04, administration

Is there a GUI tool for managing systemd on Ubuntu 18.04 (Bionic Beaver)?

I want to be able to see the status of services and/or units (and/or whatever else systemd calls them).

Ideally, I could also filter so as to only display running services.  I'd also be able to filter to only display enabled services.

Apparently, Ubuntu 16.04 had [`systemd-ui`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&searchon=sourcenames&keywords=systemd-ui), which I never used.

This [article from 2011](https://www.linux.com/learn/managing-services-linux-systemd) mentions some other tools that existed long ago on various Linux distributions.

If there is not a GUI tool, is there a curses tool?

I want to be able to quickly review a list of running and enabled services, and in as few key presses as possible, stop and disable the services/units that I don't want.

Thanks!

Comment: You may find Cockpit Project helpful. It's available under GNU LGPL.
https://cockpit-project.org/

Answer (score 18):

I'm surprised no one has mentioned [chkservice](https://github.com/linuxenko/chkservice) yet. A curses tool for enabling,disabling, and starting/stopping systemd units. It's even in the usual apt repo, so you can just `sudo apt install chkservice`.

[image]

Comment: I tried, but it has cryptic stuff like `[s]`, `[x]`, `-m-` (it doesn't explain what these mean). The idea of a GUI is that it's not cryptic like the non-GUI version. But thanks for the software recommendation.

Comment: Try hitting `?` for the help screen. It includes a legend to the cryptic stuff:
`[x] - enabled unit  [ ] - disabled unit  [s] - static unit   -m- - masked unit`

Comment: deeply disappointed with this one. I'm trying to build a timer here and it's showing as `-m-` without explanation or hint. can't restart or do anything, do not get any help msg from the likes of systemd or chkservice. In for another day of googling and tinkering BECAUSE ALL OF THESE THINGS ARE BY NERDS FOR NERDS ONLY

Comment: John, I assume you saw the comment right above your own which said `-m- - masked unit`. Does that help you?

Comment: @JohnFrazer: systemd is a core infrastructure software for system administration and management. So yes, ALL OF THESE THINGS ARE FOR SYSTEM ADMINISTRATORS ONLY. Some learning is expected and required. It's not meant for end users.

Comment: @MestreLion Systemd is not meant for end users?  Please tell that to the Ubuntu/Gnome folks that decided to run `systemd --user` when a user logs in.

Comment: @hackerb9: `systemd --user` is a systemd feature enabled in virtually all modern distros, so not an Ubuntu or Gnome thing. And being called "--user" does not make that feature intended to be used by the average joe, GUI end user. Just like `crontab` and so many other user tools.

Comment: I'm saying that you're _right_ that systemd is not suitable for people who have not taken the time to learn it. Ubuntu used to allow users to control their accounts without having to learn systemd. You'd just fiddle with the autostart settings (or, for the old school, edit the .Xsession) to pick what runs in the background on login. Now, Gnome launches dozens of processes via `systemd --user` and folks who haven't learned it are mystified at what is launching them and how they can be stopped. "Systemd is not meant for end users" is true, but how do we help end users who have problems with it?

Comment: @hackerb9: that I completely agree. Systemd desperately needs a good, official, modern GUI.

Answer (score 9):

These five...

- KDE: [SystemdGenie](https://github.com/KDE/systemdgenie) (= [Kcmsystemd](https://github.com/rthomsen/kcmsystemd) for KDE 5)
- GTK: Systemd System Manager - Last Update 2015
- GTK: Systemd Manager  - Website down
- Web: Cockpit
- GNOME extension [Systemd manager](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/4174/systemd-manager/)

...are listed here:

- EN: https://www.linux-magazine.com/Issues/2017/199/Systemd-Graphical-Tools
- DE: https://www.linux-magazin.de/ausgaben/2017/03/bitparade/

So, if you use KDE, there may be two for you.

A screenshot of SystemdGenie:

[image: SystemdGenie]

Answer (score 8):

I'm not aware of one. It doesn't get much faster than than the CLI commands though:

```
systemctl status
systemctl stop some-service
systemctl disable some-service
```

Comment: `systemctl --type service --state running` gives a proper list of services which are currently running.

Comment: Not everyone has the memory or the knowlege to use the command line. A GUI guides a user towards the thing they are looking to do. The command line you have to do from memory. A Command Line is great for power users but not a good alternative for beginners.

Comment: you have to remember what the gui app is called, what it does (start | stop | enable | disabel) and the name of each service

Answer (score 8):

I wrote a Lua + whiptail script that can display, stop, and disable Systemd units.  The script is here:

https://github.com/mpbcode/systemctl-ui

Comment: That's useful, but not really a GUI.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using amd64 system, you can download the packages **systemd-ui_3-4_amd64.deb** and **systemd-gui_3-4_all.deb** from Xenial Repository and manually install with apt:

```
sudo apt install ./systemd-ui_3-4_amd64.deb
sudo apt install ./systemd-gui_3-4_all.deb
```

I did this and worked like a charm.

```
systemadm
```

Bibliography:

https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/systemd-ui
https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archive/primary/+files/systemd-gui_3-4_all.deb
https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archive/primary/+files/systemd-ui_3-4_amd64.deb

Answer (score 3):

Not a GUI, but a web-ui solution.

Introducing [Cockpit](https://cockpit-project.org/), a web-based server manager.

Comment: absolute life saver, no idea why this is not the actual answer

Answer (score 2):

There is also Webmin: `sudo apt install webmin`. Open a browser, fill address bar with `https://localhost:10000`. In the sidebar go to *System > Bootup and Shutdown*.