# rcconf package alternative in bionic beaver?

Tags: package-management, 18.04

I see the package has been deprecated, is there any alternative to rcconf or any other gui to manage services at startup besides update-rc.d?

Comment: AFAIK it seems that [`systemd-ui`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/admin/systemd-ui) is obsolete, so you should use `systemctl` in terminal. Also see [this article](http://www.linux-magazine.com/Issues/2017/199/Systemd-Graphical-Tools).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a GUI tool for managing systemd on Ubuntu 18.04 (Bionic Beaver)?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1030850/is-there-a-gui-tool-for-managing-systemd-on-ubuntu-18-04-bionic-beaver)

Answer (score 4):

On Ubuntu 18.04 LTS you can use SystemD GUI module from KDE Control Center (packaged as [`kde-config-systemd`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/kde-config-systemd)). Its description is below:

> KDE control center module for Systemd
>    This package is a KDE Control Center module for the systemd daemon.
>    It is capable of starting and stopping systemd units.
>    In addition, it allows for the configuration of several systemd
>    parameters.

You can install with:

```
sudo apt install kde-config-systemd kde-cli-tools
```

And then run with:

```
kcmshell5 kcm_systemd
```

It looks like:

[image]