# sysv-rc-conf AND rcconf

Tags: command-line, startup, services, alternative, automatic

it seems that sysv-rc-conf and rcconf is not available in 18.04.
Is there any alternatives for user, who connects into Ubuntu 18 system remotelly via Putty? 
Thank you.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1043248/rcconf-package-alternative-in-bionic-beaver  and  https://askubuntu.com/questions/1030850/is-there-a-gui-tool-for-managing-systemd-on-ubuntu-18-04-bionic-beaver   You should learn the systemctl commands. There are basically only 4 that are important  ;-)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [rcconf package alternative in bionic beaver?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1043248/rcconf-package-alternative-in-bionic-beaver)